Не обновляется перевод django
Почему-то не обновляется перевод слова "Home" в Django.
django.po
#: core/templates/core/layout.html:59 core/templates/core/layout.html:112
msgid "Home"
msgstr "Главная"

Django автоматически перевел это как начало и теперь, когда пытаюсь обновить перевод, "home" все еще "начало"
